# Visual Studio 2015 + XInput + XP toolset

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-xp, xinput

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that uses Input: XInput9_1_0.lib is added to the linker dependencies and everything works fine when using the default toolset (v140).

In order to allow my code to run on XP I chnaged the toolset to v140_xp. Now everything compiles fine, but I get an linker error ("cannot open input file 'XInput9_1_0.lib'").

I've searched for XInput9_1_0.lib on my C drive and I can only find it in folders:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86

So I guess the one that was used with toolset v140 is no longer searched with toolset v140_xp.

What is the proper way to solve my issue ?